# Generate 64bit int in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

what better way to generate a 64 bit number in nodejs (js)? 
Whether to use Math.random() function? Example,

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*(9223372036854775807-1+1)+1);
```

Thanks.

Update: I just need to randomly generate. Can I generate two 32-bit numbers, convert them to a string and concatenate them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [node-int64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-int64) package for 64bit integer as Javascript does not support 64 bit integers.

Also refer, [node-bigint](https://github.com/substack/node-bigint)